# No Sites Folder in Mountain Lion after Upgrade

Tags: macos, webserver

> After i upgraded Mountain Lion on my MacBook Air, i haven't any Sites
>   folder in my home-folder.

On my Mac Mini there is still my Sites folder with all my local sites in it.

**How do i get it back?**

- XAMPP is installed
- XCode is installed
- Developer tools are installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just recreating the folder and naming it the same thing? I don't believe the folder is created when you install developer tools. It should be there due to Safari.

Comment: Simple Trick - solved my problem! Thank you! But i'm a german user, so sites is normally translated in "websites". So something is wrong... but it works!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad that worked :)